# Meteor Jquery event to change to new background image on hover

Tags: jquery, meteor

Requirement:  Change background image on hover to a new image.

I have some 4 images for which I want a new image to b displayed  in background every time hover.

> This particular thing works without meteor but not on meteor. I am new
>   to it and pretty much clueless.

```
<body>
    <a href="#" id="yes" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" id="no" class="btn btn-danger">No</a>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
Template.body.events({
    "mouseover #no": function(){
        console.log ("mouseover success");
        var imgs=['http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg','http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg','http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg','https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'];
        var current = imgs.indexOf($('body').css('background-image'));
        $('body').css('background-image',imgs[++current] || imgs[0]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew! Your code is not very "Meteor-like." I'd strongly recommend checking out more tutorials and learning how things are typically structured in Meteor. The less jQuery you use to manipulate the DOM, the better (though changing styles is not really a big deal in this case). In the mean time, though, try this instead: (this code is untested)

```
Template.body.onCreated(function () {
  Session.set('images', 
    [
      'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg',
      'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg', 
      'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg', 
      'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'
    ]);
  Session.set('currImage', 0);
});

Template.body.events({
  "mouseover #no": function () {
    var imgs = Session.get('images');

    Session.set('currImage', Session.get('currImage') + 1);

    Template.instance().$('body').css('background-image',
      imgs[Session.get('currImage')] || imgs[0]);
  }
});
```

This is also just quick and dirty. I probably wouldn't use `Session` here, and I certainly wouldn't dump everything in the `body` either, you should be using templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mouseenter instead of mouseover. See event documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) to see supported events.

```
"mouseenter #no": function(){
```

Comment: event is functioning. the issue is with the jquery!